# How to add reset button in webform?

Tags: forms, webforms

I tried to use below code to add reset button in webform,but its not working.I think that is not calling to "contact_form_reset" this function.Please help me out..

```
function cap_academy_contactus_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
       if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_860'){
        $form['actions']['reset'] = array(
          '#type' => 'submit',
          '#value' => t('Reset fields'),
          '#submit' => array('contact_form_reset'),
          '#prefix' => '<div class="contactform">',
                '#suffix' => '</div>'   
        );
        return $form;
      }
    }

    function contact_form_reset($form, &$form_state){
      $form_state['rebuild'] = FALSE;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use #button_type and #attributes onclick  like this.

```
$form['reset'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#button_type' => 'reset',
    '#value' => t('Reset'),
    //'#weight' => 9,
    //'#access' => FALSE,
    //'#disabled' => TRUE,
    '#validate' => array(),
    '#attributes' => array(
          'onclick' => 'this.form.reset(); return false;',
        ),
    '#prefix' => '',
    '#sufix' => '',
);
```

Another option is to use Ajax like this.In the callback we can reset all form elements to default.I tried using $form_state['rebuild'] in there but it didn't work in my case.

```
 $form['reset'] = array(
     '#type' => 'button',
     '#value' => t('Reset all'),
     '#ajax' => array(
         'callback' => 'my_ajax_reset_all',
     ),
     //'#limit_validation_errors' => array(''),       // No validation.
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but i want to do that using Form api only, not using javascript functions.

Answer (score 0):

Webform is a drupal form and you can use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/hook_form_alter): Lets say you have a custom module called **mymodule** and your webform id is '**webform_client_form_XXXXX**'. Then use the sample code below.

Here, XXXX is the form-id used in webform.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter.
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'webform_client_form_XXXXX':
      $form['actions']['custom_submit']  = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Reset'),
        '#submit' => array('mymodule_custom_submit'),
      );
      $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_custom_validate';
      break;
  }
}
/**
 * Custom validation handler for your webform.
 */
function mymodule_custom_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  // your validation code
}
/**
 * Custom submit handler for your form
 */
function mymodule_custom_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // your submit handler code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. My doubt is where can i use "$form_state['rebuild'] = FALSE;" in your code.

Comment: we dont't require rebuild code.

Comment: Then how the form fields will get reset..?